# Storing and updating data in shiny

Tags: r, shiny

I created a shiny app and was doing some test runs today, and it stopped working suddenly. I was getting the error below.

```
 Error in curl::curl_download(input, tmpFile, mode = "wb", quiet = !showProgress) : 
  Timeout was reached: [] Connection timed out after 10002 milliseconds
```

I figured out the problem; my code uses data taken directly from a site that is unreachable today. So I was unable to access it. I saw some articles about storing data, but my issue is these data get updated by the concerned authority every few months.

Is it possible to store data somewhere and then make it update every few months? What is the best way to do this?

This is my data.

```
dM1 <- fread('https://psl.noaa.gov/data/correlation/mei.data',header = FALSE,fill = TRUE)
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: You need to figure out when people from the noaa update their data and the pattern of the latest URLs. Then you can write a script to get the data once in a while.

Comment: I was hoping for help in part in the script. Best function or package to use in these scenarios.